# Extract boot.img issues

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, boot

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to extract a boot.img. Its one of Samsung's with the funky headers so none of the scripts work. I tried HEX editing it so it is a gzip (1f 8b 08) and removing whats in front of the 1f (kernel i believe) but to no avail. All i need to do is get to init.rc and edit it then re-pack.

Comment: Samsung's boot images are different, and they are not in `img` format IIRC, rather they use their own `rfs` (That's what it is AFAICT)

Comment: am i allowed to link to a download site?
because i will just upload the boot.img

Comment: Dont know if i am allowed but here is the boot.img. If someone couple please extract it and send me the files / tell me how they did it then i would be truely grateful.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0rswokt4a7l4nj/boot.img

Comment: Look [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1929222)

Comment: I found that before but i just tried again, and as with all of the other tries/ways and i still get the same cpio error.This is only part of the output for it was too long.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6e3cse4rbq2s3tf/cpio.txt